# How can I customize SyncUser of Realm Platform?

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, realm-object-server

### Question

Is there a way to add more info to the SyncUser object of Realm Platform?
Should I override SyncUser?

### Version of Realm and Tooling

> Realm: 4.3.1
>  RealmSwift: 4.3.1
>   Xcode: 11.3.1
>  Swift: 5.1.3

Comment: That's a little vague. What kind of 'more info' are you referring to?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want to add more properties(like image, blood type, nickname etc...)

Comment: SyncUser is not something stored in your Realm - well, it is, but it's not really for that. I would suggest creating a UserObject with the properties you want to store and when the user authenticates, load that information from Realm.